# Custom shutter button in cameraOverlayView not executing

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, cameraoverlayview

I am making a custom camera in Swift. I declared it global like this:

```
let image = UIImagePickerController()
```

I have made `OverlayVC (UIViewController)` in IB. Made a shutter button and hooked it up like this:

```
@IBAction func shutterTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    print("shutterTapped")
    image.takePicture()
}
```

I instantiate this overlay before presenting:

```
image.delegate = self
image.sourceType = .camera
image.cameraDevice = .front
image.allowsEditing = false
let overlay = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OverlayVC")
image.cameraOverlayView = overlay?.view
image.showsCameraControls = false
self.present(image, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now when I run the build on device and tap on the shutter button, I can visually see it being tapped (fade out/in) but the code in **`shutterTapped()`** never executes.

Comment: simplest question: have you tried to reconnect IBAction?

Comment: @Miknash Just tried and it did not help.

Comment: I think that your action needs to be connected with controller "OverlayVC" and then via delegate notice controller from which you are calling take picture. Simply connect IBAction with OverlayVC and check if that one is called. If that works I will write down the code needed for propagation of the event to the calling view controller

Comment: @Miknash But I am not even able to print to log from this IBAction let alone post a notification to other VC.

Comment: is shutterTapped in the OverlayVC or in the view controller calling UIImagePickerController?

Comment: @Miknash shutterTapped is in OverlayVC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167835/discussion-between-kashif-and-miknash).

Comment: It's the best if you can give us a debug repo. If you can't, please update your question with image from storyboard for shutter button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why is it not really working?**

Adding view of the view controller removes controller itself and no one can actually get the event. So, you get the view but not events. and to support this:

[image]

**Solution that will actually work with your code would be:**

```
image.cameraOverlayView = overlay?.view
if let viewController  = overlay {

    for view in viewController.view.subviews {
        if let button = view as? UIButton {
           button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.takePicture), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)
        }
    }
}
```

You can also add tag to it so you can check which button is which if you have more of them.

**Alternate Solution:**

Create `UIView` subclass and xib for it. Same view you had in the `OverlayVC`. Then, when adding overlay use following:

```
image.sourceType = .camera
image.cameraDevice = .front
image.allowsEditing = false
let myOverlay = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CameraOverlay", owner: self, options: nil)
image.cameraOverlayView = myOverlay?.first as! UIView
image.showsCameraControls = false
self.present(image, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Note that force unwrap should be protected with either `guard` or `if let` when casting to `UIView`.

Comment: Great, glad to help. Don’t forget to assign bounty as well